# Relativistic Fluid Equation - Density Perturbations in Cosmology

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, astrophysics, perturbation-theory

While I am deriving the relativistic fluid equation for the radiation component I am getting an extra term like $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}P$ where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity and $P$ is the pressure.

Is this term is equal to $0$? How can I prove that is the case?